# Inverse limit of $\Bbb Q/q\Bbb Z$ isomorphic to finite adeles?

Tags: nt.number-theory, harmonic-analysis, profinite-groups, adeles

Let $\Bbb Q/q\Bbb Z$, for some positive rational $q$, denote the quotient group of the discrete rationals by the subgroup of integers times $q$.

For any $q_1, q_2 \in \Bbb Q^+$ and $n \in \Bbb N^+$ such that $q_2 = n \cdot q_1$, we can form a surjective homomorphism $\Bbb Q/q_2\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Q/q_1\Bbb Z$.

The set of all such $\Bbb Q/q\Bbb Z$ forms a poset with these surjections, and we can take the inverse limit to get something like a "rational solenoid."

1. Is this group isomorphic to the finite adele ring $\Bbb A_\Bbb Q^f \cong \Bbb Q \otimes \hat{\Bbb Z}$?
2. Is this group equal to the same thing you'd get if you took the inverse limit of $\Bbb Q/n\Bbb Z$ for a natural number $n$ instead of a positive rational $q$?

For #1, I think it is, because the dual group should be a direct limit of localizations of $\hat{\Bbb Z}$, the group of profinite integers, which I believe is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q \otimes \hat{\Bbb Z}$, which is self-dual. The same reasoning applies for #2.

This question was originally asked on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449189/inverse-limit-of-bbb-q-q-bbb-z-isomorphic-to-finite-adeles). It got upvoted but no answers, so I'm giving it a shot to repost here.

Comment: Yes and yes. Take Pontryagin duals! Then you're just asking whether the direct limit of qZ's is isomorphic to the direct limit of 1/n*Z's is isomorphic to Q, which is obvious.

Comment: What's $\hat {\Bbb Z}$ here?

Comment: The group of profinite integers - edited

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For 1 you can indeed use duality, but you can also give an explicit isomorphism:

First for each rational number $q$ it is easy to see that $\mathbb{A}^{f}/(q \hat{\mathbb{Z}}) \simeq \mathbb{Q}/(q\mathbb{Z})$: indeed, $(q \hat{\mathbb{Z}})$ is open and $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in the finite adeles, so the image from $\mathbb{Q}$ to this quotient is surjective and its kernel is $q \mathbb{Z}$.

So any finite adele gives you an element of the projective limit,  this element is zero if and only if the adele $x$ you started from is in $q \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ for each $q$ which implies it is zero hence the adele inject into the projective limit.

Conversely, you need to work just a little more but an element $y$ of the projective limit is the data of a compatible familly of $y_q \in \mathbb{Q}/(q \mathbb{Z})$. pick for each $y$ a lifting of $y_q$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ the compatiblity of the familly implies that $q_y$ is a cauchy net (for the divisibility order on rational numbers of course, if you don't like net then $y_{n!}$ is going to be a cauchy sequence that works equally well) in $\mathbb{A}^f$ which hence converge to an adele $x$ whose images in $\mathbb{Q}/(q \mathbb{Z})$ are the $y_q$.

For your second question, the answer is also yes: you can either do the exact same proof as above and check that the integer are enough for the arguments to work. Or observe that in your projective limit $\mathbb{N}^* \subset \mathbb{Q}^*$ is cofinal for the ordering and hence the projective limit indexed by $\mathbb{N}^*$ and by $\mathbb{Q}^*$ are the same.

Comment: By the way the OP means isomorphism as topological groups, but both objects are naturally topological rings (for the inverse limit, it's an easy verification), so it's quite natural to expect that some isomorphism is more natural than others and the isomorphism given here is indeed a ring isomorphism.

Comment: For the cofinality argument, it seems that the point is that $\mathbb{N}^*$ is cofinal in $\mathbb{Q}^*$ endowed with the divisibility ordering?

Comment: The map in the answer is by construction a continuous ring morphism, and it is not very hard to see it is also an homeomorphism but something need to be said. For the other remarks I will edit that.

Comment: Would you please chat briefly about an apparently random question about this? Literally 3-4 minutes I'd really appreciate to pick your brains.